# dustjs, duplication check while looping

Tags: dust.js

While templating, what is the way to check if an array has same value? 
I would like to skip if the array has duplicate value.

```
[
  {name: 1},
  {name: 3},
  {name: 3},
  {name: 4}
]
```

Sould out 1,3,4 on loop basically. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, Dust follows a philosophy that you should keep logic about your data out of the template. If you need to adjust your data before rendering it, you can write a helper function to pass the data through. Here's an example that uses Lodash's `uniqBy` to do this.

**Context**

```
{
  yourArray: [{name: 1}, {name: 3}, {name: 3}, {name: 4}],
  unique: function(chunk, context, bodies, {values, by}) {
    const uniqueValues = _.uniqBy(values, by);
    return chunk.section(uniqueValues, context, bodies);
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
{#unique values=yourArray by="name"}
  {name}{~n}
{/unique}
```

In this example, I've defined a context helper `unique` that accepts two parameters, an array to filter and a key to filter by.

I call `_.uniqBy` to filter the array, and then use `chunk.section` to render my block once for each value in `uniqueValues`.

Then, in the template, I call my context helper `{#unique}` and pass it the parameters.

Comment: This is great. I was able to run helper but I dont have the lodash. If possible and if you could help with vanillajs implementation that would be  just great. I am confused on the deconstracting part.

Comment: Also I get "error: ReferenceError: params is not defined" error for this.

Comment: Edited; just remove `params` from the `chunk.section` call. I destructured params into `{values, by}` and forgot to change other usages.